# Validation array

Tags: arrays, laravel, validation, tags

I have a tags in my project but tags is created by me and user can checked what he want. It works correctly but I have a problem with Validation. In my store function I have an array and I want to validate any single element. I wrote this validate rule:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->tags, [
            'id' => 'integer|max:15'
 ]);
```

It doesn't work. Why?

Comment: dd($request->tags) paste the output

Comment: And type the error you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this

```
[
   'tags' => 'array',
   'tags.*' => 'integer|max:15'
]
```